# How configure SSO with Azure AD B2C and ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I need help understanding how to implement SSO.

I have two SPAs that authenticate through an ASP.NET Core Web API, the login method implemented in this API checks credentials by making a call to the MSAL API using Azure AD B2C.

After this verification, the credentials are checked again by consulting the ASP.NET Identity tables to obtain the user's roles and claims. After these two steps, the JWT token is generated and returned to the frontend that requested it.

I need to implement SSO in this flow, allowing the user to authenticate in one of the SPAs and when traveling to the other SPA they do not need to authenticate again.

I've already researched Auth0 and adding Google as an Idp, but I believe I'm on the wrong path. Can anyone guide me on how to resolve this challenge?